# Should there be comma between 'me' and 'too'?

Tags: grammar

As 'I can, too,' 'I can, either,' I think there should be comma between 'me' and 'too' because it seems like 'wow you are here,' but not 'wow, you are here.'

Comment: 'Me too' informally replaces answers such as 'I do, too', 'So have I', 'I would, too' - depending on what statement they are agreeing with. So the subject is _me_ (standing in for _i_) and _too_ modifies the unspoken verb.

Comment: I guess the ["Me too movement"](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk01iUecuTEdHJDwa8U1ebmHxL0sRPA%3A1601285874350&ei=8q5xX5n5FImcgQajuZDgCA&q=%22me+too+movement%22&oq=%22me+too+movement%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQDDIGCAAQBxAeMggIABAHEAoQHjIGCAAQBxAeMgIILjICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADoECAAQRzoFCC4QkwI6BAgAEENQ0g5Y_yxgujxoAHABeACAAYoBiAHtApIBAzEuMpgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrIAQjAAQE&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiZuuXdxovsAhUJTsAKHaMcBIwQ4dUDCA0) has not been publicised much beyond the western hemisphere.

Comment: https://painintheenglish.com/case/176 and https://www.bellenglish.com/blog/english-tips-how-use-me-too-and-me-neither/ (any user is welcomed to use the links I posted in their answer, as I don't have the time to write a comprehensive post)

Comment: @Kate Bunting I change question.

Comment: "I can either" makes no sense to me. Is it a mistake?

Comment: Your edit seems to have made this even more difficult to understand. Do you want to roll it back?